# Upload images in media with out login in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can add in an image in media library without login?

I can upload images from admin but  can't upload image through not logged in user.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the original question.

Comment: <code><input type="button" value="Add Gallery" onclick="showAddPhotos();"/>
function showAddPhotos()
{
var file_frame;
if ( file_frame ) {
    file_frame.open();
    return;
}
file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
title: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_title' ),
button: {
text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' ),
},
multiple: true  
});
file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
var selection = file_frame.state().get('selection');
selection.map( function( attachment ) {
attachment = attachment.toJSON();
file_frame.open();
}<code>
This is my code .

Answer (score -2):

you can go to your cpanel>file maneger and find media folder in oublic html

Comment: First: OP talks about Wordpress. It wont appear in your media libary this way. Wordpress misses the entry in the database about this item, thus not seeing it there, and ignoring the uploaded content. It can be acces by link off course, but it wont appear in your libary, nor will it perform the resize options.. And it goes in upload folder in wp-content, rather than what you say.

Comment: No,  Uplode image from frontend form without login. for guest

Comment: When I log in as a Super Admin I can upload the image with no problems. It's when the user logins that the error is happening. Each user is the Admin of their own site.